# Display a splash while app is unpacking from onefile mode PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, exe, pyinstaller, splash-screen

Hi I have a quite large kivy & gstreamer app for windows, and I want it to be compiled in one file, I use the onefile function in pyinstaller, but it takes a while to load, I know the reason why, and my question is, how can I display a splash screen while pyinstaller is unpacking the files from the exe before loading, so the user can understand that the app is loading? Is there any solution? And it should use PyInstaller not other solutions, because kivy with gstreamer can only be compiled using pyinstaller (from the official docs).

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller adding splash screen or visual feedback during file extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315785/pyinstaller-adding-splash-screen-or-visual-feedback-during-file-extraction)

Comment: This question has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315785/pyinstaller-adding-splash-screen-or-visual-feedback-during-file-extraction) for example). There is no current fix for --onefile executables. There are two possibilities, either create a new --onefile that starts up a splash screen and then the other executable in some way or use --onedir instead. --onedir is much faster in general, plus you can add a splash screen in some other way. If you use an installer, you can bundle the onedir with a shortcut to it too so that it looks like a --onefile.